# Using recursion to find sum of geometric sequence

Tags: java, recursion

```
    public static double sumGeom(double term, double ratio, int n)
    {
        double sum = 0;

        if (n<=1)
        {
            return term;
        }
        else
        {
            sum = sum + term * ratio;
            return sumGeom(term * ratio, ratio, n-1);
        }
    }
}

//Geometric sequence: 2 4 8 16 32
//Geometric sum: 62
```

I am a beginner to Java, and my assignment was to find the sum of a geometric sequence using recursion only.

The parameters are: term = 2, ratio = 2 and n = 5. Above is the code that I attempted. I am having a very hard time visualize how recursions work, so I do not know what went wrong with my code. Instead of giving me the desired answer of 62, I am getting 32 instead. What is wrong with this code?

I have tried this version as well but am still getting 32 instead of 62:

```
public static double sumGeom(double term, double ratio, int n)
{
    double sum = 0;

    if (n<=1)
    {
        return term;
    }
    else
    {
        return sum = sum + sumGeom(term * ratio, ratio, n-1);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What parameters are you passing to the method?

Comment: Do you know what a debugger is? Run your code under the debugger and go through it step by step. You'll learn a lot.

Comment: Wouldn't it be clever to actually do something with `sum`? Like using it to calculate the return value?

Comment: This is because you are ignoring 'sum' variable in recursion calls, and you end up with returning only last item from geometric sequence. You should rather return sum + sumGeom(...).

Comment: I returned sum + sumGeom(...) but it still doesn't work

Comment: Now come on, please think before trying random stuff. Your `sum` will always be `0.0`, what do you expect here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You need to understand how recursion works.

Your first answer, You are not using sum and what is going on is you just multiply term with ratio and you get the output 32.

```
   public static double sumGeom(double term, double ratio, int n)
    {
        double sum = 0;

        if (n<=1)
        {
            return term;
        }
        else
        {
            sum = sum + term * ratio;
            return sumGeom(term * ratio, ratio, n-1);
        }
    }
```

Your second answer, one error in both of your answers is you are redefining your sum to 0 so basically you are adding 0 + term * ratio each time.

```
public static double sumGeom(double term, double ratio, int n)
{
    double sum = 0;

    if (n<=1)
    {
        return term;
    }
    else
    {
        return sum = sum + sumGeom(term * ratio, ratio, n-1);

    }
}
```

**Correct Way (solution)**

In this we add term back to itself to get the sum of all the values returned.

```
public static double sumGeom(double term, double ratio, int n)
    {
        if (n<=1)
        {
            return term;
        }
        else
        {
            term = term + sumGeom(term * ratio, ratio, n-1);

            return term;
        }
    }
```

If you want to see how it goes in and returns and what are the values at each step try this solution

```
public static double sumGeom(double term, double ratio, int n)
{
    if (n<=1)
    {

        System.out.println("term : "+ term + " ");

        System.out.println("ratio : "+ ratio + " ");

        System.out.println("n : " + n);

        return term;
    }
    else
    {

        System.out.println("term : "+ term + " ");

        System.out.println("ratio : "+ ratio + " ");

        System.out.println("n : " + n);

        term = term + sumGeom(term * ratio, ratio, n-1);

        System.out.println("term : "+ term + " ");

        System.out.println("ratio : "+ ratio + " ");

        System.out.println("n : " + n);

        return term;
    }
}

//Result will be this
term : 2.0 
ratio : 2.0 
n : 5
term : 4.0 
ratio : 2.0 
n : 4
term : 8.0 
ratio : 2.0 
n : 3
term : 16.0 
ratio : 2.0 
n : 2
term : 32.0 
ratio : 2.0 
n : 1
term : 48.0 
ratio : 2.0 
n : 2
term : 56.0 
ratio : 2.0 
n : 3
term : 60.0 
ratio : 2.0 
n : 4
term : 62.0 
ratio : 2.0 
n : 5
result : 62.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need variable `sum`.
Let's look the last call of recursion. The parameters will be `sumGeo(32, 2, 1)` and you will return `sum + sumGeo()` and that is `0 + 32`. And that will be the value that the method returns.
Recursion is not easy to understand, especially for someone who is a beginner in programming.
Try to visualize each method call. Also, you can use a debugger in your IDE to find out what is happening in the code.

Try something like this

```
public static double sumGeom(double term, double ratio, int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return term;
    }

    System.out.println("term: " + term);
    return term + sumGeom(term * ratio, ratio, n - 1);
}
```